# How to play streaming PCM data from server like Android AudioTrack class?

Tags: ios, pcm, audiotrack, audioqueue

I try to develop iOS PCM streaming app.

Before it, I have developed Android app with AudioTrack class, audio playing is very well in long time.

In iOS, I use AudioQueue APIs.

AudioQueue play streamed PCM data very well for a few seconds,

but soon playing sound is on and off. What can I do?

(still streaming, and queueing AudioQueue)

I want to make app that like Android app with AudioTrack class.

Please give me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it.
The solution is using "AudioUnit" APIs.
AudioUnit is lower level API than AudioQueue.

please refer to documents about AudioUnit & AudioOutputUnitStart